# Semantic-UI multiple sidebars pushing each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I'm looking for a good way to realize a sort of breadcrumb navigation through a database using Semantic-UI (on top of Django, if that matters). The idea is to click on a link toggling the first sidebar, showing a dataset with in a form with each data offering a link to dig further down, opening the dug down data in another sidebar, shifting the parent further to the left. So in the end you end up with a horizontal "timeline" of sorts, made up of sidebars (or something else) that the user can then step back through, shifting everything back to the right.

The default sidebars seem to always overlay each other, so basically the question is, how do you make new sidebars shift existing ones?